# Framework for designing Blockchain (in combination with secure multi-party computation)

Tags: blockchain

I'm looking for a framework where I can build my own blockchain. In my case I wan't to combine the blockchain with secure multi-party computation algorithm.
Means that two or more parties want to exchange data without revealing the input data...

are there any good framework you can recommend? (Free or academic access etc.)
I found Openchain and Nstratis... maybe there are better ones?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find hyperledger fabric useful for your purposes : [Hyperledger Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/)